# "Package dependencies cannot be resolved" while installing  Chromium browser

Tags: installation, package-management, chromium, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Package dependencies cannot be resolved” error when installing software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101822/package-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved-error-when-installing-software)

I installed 12.04 in my system. While trying to install Chromium, I get the following error:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. 
Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
chromium-browser: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
                  Depends: libudev0 (>= 147) but 175-0ubuntu9 is to be installed
                  Depends: libxss1 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
                  Depends: libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.3) but it is not going to be installed
```

Can any one solve the issue please?