# Dependencies | not able to install from Ubuntu Software Center | Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dependencies

I am not able to download and install programs (including vlc and unity tweak tool) from the Ubuntu Software Center. Every time i try to get them, there is a dependency error and i am completely lost now.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit).

***More Details:***

```
**Package dependencies cannot be resolved**
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.3 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libtar0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

---

***Results of commands requested:***

**sudo apt-get update**
 & **sudo apt-get upgrade**
& **sudo apt-get install -f**

*result*: [http://imgur.com/Qm4MpBD,6iEK7Ii,u3fKB8J,PxMu2fD,jSlxc7g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvS8s.png)

**sudo apt-get update** && **sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a** && **sudo apt-get -f install -y**

*result:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9jlx.png

Comment: Can you append your question to add the output of the commands `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Need more info, try `sudo apt-get update && sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a && sudo apt-get -f install -y`.

Comment: Have you ever installed any software using a downloaded .deb file that wasn't from the default Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: I don't think so. Have updated the Question to provide further clarification.

Moreover, this problem persists since the first day of installing 14.04 version.

Comment: Have updated the output of commands in the question to provide more info.

Looking forward for insights of both of you.

Comment: @CharlesGreen need you help people.

Comment: @przemo need you help people.

Comment: @AG322336 I looks as though you are pulling from a non-US mirror for the ubuntu updates - is this correct?  I think you'll need to from `sudo apt-get update` until it manages to connect to all the archives, then to an update.  You might try changing the mirror that you are referring to.

Comment: @AG322336, what does `@przemo need you help people.` mean? If you are making logs of commands and their output use for example `script -a log.txt` not the screenshots, which are useless. To finish recording press `Ctrl + D`. It looks like you messed up apt sources, so google `apt sources.list ubuntu`.

Comment: @CharlesGreen yes that was the real issue. I figured it out by continuosly trying to find the solution changed the mirror and it resolved all the problems.
I was here to communicate the solution and read your solution. And yes you are right.
By the way, Thank you. Much appreciated.

Comment: @przemo I am new to this stuff, that's why didn't know how to write professionally.
Hope will understand in a timely manner.

Regarding the problem, it is resolved. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Ubuntu Update menu, by changing the mirror from non-US to US, I was able to download all the required packages and the problem of dependencies is resolved.

Moreover, Now I am able to install any software from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 2):

Open System Settings -> Software and Updates -> Ubuntu Software tab -> Download from -> Other -> Select best server -> choose the best server
and update your system once you have selected the best server

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I plugged my laptop into a wired internet connection and updated the software repositories. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

To get all missing dependencies open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Didn't resolve the problem. Have updated the results of commands in the question , kindly can you review it again.

Comment: Didn't resolve the issue for me either. Same system, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Search software and update.Go to Update software menu.In download from option select appropriate server from list.
Like I am from India and I selected other >> India >> ftp.iitb.ac.in (server in IIT-Bombay).
This worked for me and I am able to install any software.

In case it doesn't work let me know so that I can suggest you other required settings for software and update.