# Package dependencies

Tags: mount, dependencies

I am installing vlc in ubuntu 14.04 then its showing some error..

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Comment: Do you have the Universe repo enabled?

Comment: Does this answer help http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3581/unable-to-install-vlc

Comment: what is this repo? please explain this sir.

Comment: Also, http://askubuntu.com/questions/518379/dependencies-not-able-to-install-from-ubuntu-software-center-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Repo means repository, see here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

To install automatically all dependencies,

Open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Don't post what you think is a comment in the answer section, the limitation exists for a reason, you only need 50 rep to comment, earn it. As it happens, this is a valid answer on its own.

Answer (score 0):

---

Did you forget to do `sudo apt-get update`? ( updates the package lists.)

The install command for vlc :

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc`

---