# how to install wine windows program loader?

Tags: 14.04, wine, winetricks

I tried to install wine but there is a message appears

[image]

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You're probably missing the gist of the error message by taking a picture.  If you actually typed the text of the message in the question the **AU** site would automatically give you lots of resolutions.  Look at [Google Search - package dependencies cannot be resolved](https://www.google.com/#q=%22package+dependencies+cannot+be+resolved%22).  One of the many resolutions is [Askubuntu - “Package dependencies cannot be resolved” error when installing software](http://askubuntu.com/questions/101822/package-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved-error-when-installing-software)

Comment: It's all within the **Details**

Answer (score 0):

A general catch-all for install issues is `apt install -f` which should attempt to resolve all package dependencies and fix your issue.

this should have been a comment but I can't? Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these instructions: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu. They worked pretty well for me. Plus it uses the latest versions

Answer (score 0):

You will find complete instructions on https://wiki.winehq.org/Download. You can check out the page for different types of linux distros.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu; while this link may answer the question, it's better to include essential parts here. It will become invalid if the website is removed or modified.